# Spring 3.2 Error when start tomcat server 7 - BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tomcat7

I have this problem when I start tomcat 7:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class    
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4721)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5423)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5402)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

here is my application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="true">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" annotation-config="true" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    < data source connection >
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="schemaUpdate" value="false" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ... list of classes mapped
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="auditServiceAOP" class="com.xxx.aop.AuditServiceAOP">
    <constructor-arg ref="xxxSession" />
    <constructor-arg ref="auditorshipService" />
</bean>

<bean id="auditLoginAOP" class="com.xxx.aop.AuditLoginAOP">
    <constructor-arg ref="auditorshipService" />
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionLoggerAOP" class="com.xxx.aop.ExceptionLoggingAOP" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</beans>
```

And this is my spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/pages/login.xhtml">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-success-url="/pages/login.xhtml"
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />

    <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml?error=true" 
        default-target-url="/pages/home.xhtml" 
        login-page="/pages/login.xhtml" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="xxxAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The version of spring that I'm using is 3.2.2 and the spring security version is 3.1.4.

I searched in stackoverflow but I didn't find anything that solve my problem.

I appreciate the help! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>xxx</display-name>
<!-- Spring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext-email.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>ui-lightness</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Spring security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: I update the issue. please take a look. Thanks @mthmulders

Comment: According to the stack trace, it is printed after the real error. It contains `ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed`, meaning the container is shutting down the web application. Are there any errors before the one you've shown?

Comment: Hi @mthmulders! There's one message before that: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what caused that error but I resolve that downloading the libs of spring again.